# How to provide detailed error information over SOAP with JAX WS?

Tags: soap, exception, jax-ws

I'm developing web services using a Java-first approach with JAX-WS. I'm struggling to figure out how to provide detailed error information to the web service client. Ideally, I would like to throw an instance of the class below when there are validation errors:

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception {

  private Errors errors;

  public ValidationException(Errors errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
  }

  public Errors getErrors() {
    this.errors;
  }
}
```

The `Errors` object (similar to [Spring's Errors interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html)) encapsulates:

- the fields that are in error
- the nature of each error (unique constraint violated, allowed range exceeded, etc.)

`ValidationException` is thrown by the operations of my service endpoint that perform validation, e.g.

```
public class MyEndpoint {

  public void doSomething(ValidateableInput input) throws ValidationException {
    // implementation omitted
  }
}
```

A client accesses the service using code generated by [wsimport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html). However this code does not throw an instance of my `ValidationException` class, but instead throws an instance of an exception class generated by `wsimport` (this class is also named `ValidationException` but is in a different package). The client's `ValidationException` does not contain the `Errors` object, so detailed information about the cause of the error is lost.

In the context of SOAP/JAX-WS the instance of `ValidationException` thrown by the service has to be translated to a [a SOAP fault](http://www.w3schools.com/SOAP/soap_fault.asp). I have read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-jaxws-faults/index.html) about Faults in JAX-WS which [demonstrates how to use a Fault Bean](http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html) to encapsulate further detail about your exception. However, the Fault Bean seems to be limited to:

> a Java class that has a no-arg constructor, a message String field, and a getter and setter for it. This will be your carrier for that soap:fault detail element.

so it only  provides a single String in which to encapsulate information about the cause of the error(s).

To summarise: *is it possible to provide detailed error information in the client code generated for a JAX-WS service*

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is **yes**, it is possible to provide detailed error information in WebFault.

E.g.

```
@WebFault(faultBean = "com.myexample.Errors")
public class ValidationException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Errors errors;

    public ValidationException() {
        super();
    }

    public ValidationException(String message, Errors errors, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public ValidationException(String message, Errors errors) {
        super(message);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public Errors getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

The Errors class can be defined as,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Errors", propOrder = {
    "message"
})
public class Errors {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String message;


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String value) {
        this.message = value;
    }

}
```

Like **message** variable the error class can have any number of variables which can hold values and can be accessible at client end.

Answer (score 0):

In a web service if you throw an exception, it will go to the client encapsulated in a SoapFault, but all your exception is inside it.

In your specific example, how is ValidationException declared in your WSDL? It has any field? I think your problem is the absence of a setErrors() method in your ValidationException calss. The JAXB creates the the description of your classes by default (if no JAXB annotation are used) adding as fields just what has a getter-setter pair.